# Hidden Markov model alternative that allows dependence on previous n states

Tags: markov-process

I am working on a prototype framework.

Basically I need to generate a model or profile for each individual's lifestyle based on some sensor data about him/her, such as GPS, motions, heart rate, surrounding environment readings, temperature etc.

The proposed model or profile is a knowledge representation of an individual's lifestyle pattern. Maybe a graph with probabilities.

I am thinking to use Hidden Markov Model to implement this. As the states in HMM can be Working, Sleeping, Leisure, Sport and etc. Observations can be a set of various sensor data.

My understanding of HMM is that next state S(t) is only depends on previous one state S(t-1). However in reality, a person's activity might depends on previous n states. Is it still a good idea to use HMM? Or should I use some other more appropriate models? I have seen some work on second order and multiple order of Markov Chains, does it also apply HMM?

I really appreciate if you can give me a detailed explanation.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can always construct a (standard) Markov model out of the vectors $X(t) = (S(t-n+1), S(t-n+2), \ldots, S(t))$: now each state $X(t)$ depends only on the values found in $X(t-1)$ and you're off and running.

Comment: Of course, @whuber's approach multiplies the dimension of the state space by $n$, which might cause problems in practice. You might also be interested in using [conditional random fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field), which are closely related to HMMs but make it easier to have dependencies further back in the state history.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of sensors with possibly noisy data that you want to correlate to an unknown underlying state, this seems to be a classic use case for a [Kalman filter](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/Understanding%20the%20Basis%20of%20the%20Kalman%20Filter.pdf) instead of a higher order Markov model. [Here](http://bilgin.esme.org/BitsBytes/KalmanFilterforDummies.aspx) is one tutorial of many; Google will provide much more help.  Hope this redirect helps you.